# How to convert c++ code with windows API from windows to linux automaticly

Tags: c++, linux, windows

How to convert c++ code with Windows API from Windows to Linux automatically without deleting anything. I need to do the migration of this solution from Windows to Linux to create un shared object  (.so) that I will use it to create a service in Linux

Comment: If you used Windows API deeply, there is no easy way to do that -- they are very diverse.

Comment: You'd need to create a set of functions that translate the windows API calls to their linux equivalents. It's no trivial task. They cannot always be mapped directly e.g thread handling.

Answer (score 3):

There is no automatic way to achieve this 1 to 1. Starting at the process model, thread model, file system, event mechanisms, memory model, string representation(UTF16-UTF8), etc... are different in both platforms

The best way to achieve multiplatform is to develop your app using some kind of framework like [qt](http://qt-project.org/). I'm sorry to tell you that there is no way to do what you want.

Think, if what you want here were so easy, we would have the same software on windows/linux. Companies can't afford to expend hundred of thousands of dollars to migrate their products in different platforms.